# geth gas spending is always bellow 4.7m

Tags: go-ethereum, transaction-propagation

According to my knowledge, `GETH` miners can fit many transactions on a block so long the total gas spend < block `gas limit`. However, in my lab network (private) when I bumped up miners gas limit from `4.7M` (default) to `8,000,000` I still can't fit more transactions. I monitor ethstats and gas spending never go beyond 4.7M.

Did I miss any start up flags to allow gas spending/block go higher than default 4.7M?

Answer (score 1):

What is your genesis file? What command do you use to launch geth? After changing the block gas limit did you reset your private blockchain?

Default rules only allows the gas to change about 0.1% in each block, if you didn't reset it will stay close to the old limit until enough blocks has been mined.

If you start at 4.7M you will need at least 533 blocks to be above 8M

```
4700000 * (1.001)**533 = 8006840 > 8000000
```

Comment: I'm aware of the block gas limit growing rate. I monitored ethstats it reported block gas limit reached `8000000` before I submit transactions. But it doesn't matter ethstats gas spending stats never go beyond `4.7M`.